# $u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{u_n(x)}$ converges uniformly, each with no $x^i$ in Taylor expansion, does $u(x)$ have the same property?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Problem: Suppose $u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{u_n(x)}$ and the series converges uniformly in $(-A, A)$ for some $A>0$. If for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$, $u_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{a_{n,j}x^j}$, $\forall x\in (-A,A)$ and $i>0$ is a fixed integer such that $a_{n,i}=0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. If it holds that $u(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{a_{j}x^j}$, is it true that $a_i=0$?
I have proved that that statement holds if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{u_{n}^{(k)}(x)}$ converges unoformly for $k\leq i$. proof: WLOG $i=1$. In the equality $$u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{u_n(x)}$$ take derivative of both sides, we have $$u'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{u_n'(x)}$$ Since $a_{n,1}=0$, we have $u_n'(0)=0$,$\forall n$. Hence $u'(0)=0$. Thus the Taylor expansion of $u(x)$ has no term $x$. But what if $u_n(x)$ do not have such good property? Will there then be counterexamples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A=1.$ By the Weierstrass theorem the function $|x|^{1/2}$ is the uniform limit of polynomials $p_n(x).$ We may assume $p_n(0)=0,$ i.e. $p_n(x)=xq_n(x).$ Thus $u(x)=x^2$ is the uniform limit of $x^4q_n(x)^4.$
Let $$u_n(x)=x^4[q_n(x)^4-q_{n-1}(x)^4]$$ where $q_0(x)=0.$
We get
$$u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n(x)$$ and the convergence is uniform. We have
$a_{n,2}=0$ and $a_2=1.$

Comment: Sorry for my bothering, but I don't understand what $p_n(x)$ stands for. Would you mind explaining it in detail?

Comment: I re-edited the answer. I hope it is more clear. I can still modify it if necessary.

Comment: I think I now understand it. Thank you very much! This is a concise counterexample, much less complicated than my expectation.